# A good way to associate a counter to each member of an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings in Javascript like `var elements = ["string1", "string2"]; The array is created dynamically so it could contain any number of strings. I want to associate a counter to each element of the array. The counter will increment or decrement during the webpage's life.

I was going to try `element["string1"].counter = 1`; but it didn't work.

What's a good way to implement this?

Comment: Could you include the code you tried that didn't work?

Comment: It's the line which said it didn't work. I am not sure what more you're asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also create a "hash table" using a plain object such as:

```
var counter = {};

for(var i = elements.length; i--; ) {
    counter[elements[i]] = 1;
}
```

Then you could increment the counter with:

```
counter['string1'] += 1;
```

or

```
counter[elements[0]] += 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you had an array `var elements = ["string1", "string2"]`, you could not access an element with `elements["string1"]`, you are using the value not the index.  `elements[0]` is the correct form of access to the element, using the numerical key.

Even then, strings are special types of object and do not *appear* to take additional parameters readily, at least not when I tested a moment ago. *Which is odd.*

You could quickly knock the array in to a set of objects with separate text and counter components.

```
var elements = ["string1", "string2"];
var elementsWithCounter = [];

for(var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
    elementsWithCounter[i] = { text: elements[index], counter: 1 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
elementArray = ["string1", "string2"]

function setCounter(str, val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++) {
        if (str === elementArray[i]) elementArray[i].counter = val;
    }
}

function getCounter(str) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++) {
        if (str === elementArray[i]) return elementArray[i].counter;
    }

}

setCounter("string1", 5);
getCounter("string1");
```

Alternatively just access `elementArray[index].counter`

Comment: Damn you can't do that! I really expected strings to be objects.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript primitives/built in objects can't have properties/attributes added to their prototype (i.e. String.prototype.counter = -1 doesn't work correctly).  Image, String, Date, Array all can't have properties added.

Maybe instead of a string you should make it an object, similar to what Orbling has posted.